# Linq average of dynamic double

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have a dynamic result set, which contains a key value double (but the compiler still sees it as a dynamic).  I am trying to take a cumulative average of this, but cannot figure out the correct cast or how to call the specific overload of the Linq `Average()` method.  It consistently tries to call the `Average<dynamic>(Func<dynamic, int> selector)` version, when I am pretty sure I need the `Average<dynamic>(Func<dynamic, double> selector)` version.

Intellisense on the `Average()` and `Sum()` methods is what is showing me that the compiler is choosing the `<dynamic, int>` version.  How can I specify to use the `double` version?

Here is a good sample of the iterations of things I have tried and their corresponding error. At this point, I feel I have tried every combination, and with or without `Cast<double>()` and `Convert.ToDouble()` that I can think of.

```
// ## filled with values from DB query, but here with examples ##
var result = new List<dynamic>() { new { myDouble = 0.123 }, new { myDouble = 0.456 } }; 
var cumulativeAvg = new List<double>();
```

**UPDATE** My result set turned out to have a hidden `null` value, which caused the errors:

```
var result = new List<dynamic>() {
    new { myDouble = 0.123 }
    , new { myDouble = 0.456 }
    , new { myDouble = null }
};
```

For all of the following loops, the ERROR is:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'**

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Take(i + 1).Average(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.myDouble)));

for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Take(i + 1).Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.myDouble)).Average());

for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Take(i + 1).Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.myDouble)).ToList().Average());

for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Take(i + 1).Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.myDouble)) / (i + 1));
```

For all of the following loops, the ERROR is:
**Specified cast is not valid.**

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Take(i + 1).Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.myDouble)).Cast<double>().Average());

for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Take(i + 1).Cast<double>().Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.myDouble)).Average());

for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.myDouble)).Cast<double>().Take(i + 1).Average());
```

Comment: What is `result`? Is that a typo and should be `results`? But in that case, `results` can't contain a definition for `myDouble`.

Comment: Yes typo, now fixed. `result` is the dynamic result of a DB query, which contains several values, one of which is a double. I have updated with a sample value for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working if you force the cast of the dynamic to double instead of letting the `.ToDouble` method find the appropriate type itself. Instead, do an explicit cast:

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    cumulativeAvg.Add(result.Take(i + 1).Average(r => (double)r.myDouble));
```

Comment: I actually just tried this, and found the issue. In my specific case, one of the entries has hiding a `null` value, which is why the previous `Cast()` did not work. Using this explicit cast finally brought the issue to light.